# Perform classification in R on Python where each data frame is labelled

Tags: python, r, dataframe, classification

My problem is, instead of having each row in a data frame corresponding to a label, I have multiple data frames each with the same columns and number of rows but each data frame is labelled say l1, l2 or l3. You need all the data in the data frame to be able to determine the label.

For example, say I have this data frame and its labelled l1 and imagine I have multiple more labelled l1, l2 or l3. I need to create a classification model so when I have a new data frame like this, it can classify it.

---

```
Time    Measure1  Measure2      
 1         10       1000  
 2         12       1245  
 3         20       1837  
 4         18       1837
```

How can this be structured in R or Python?

I hope that's clear!

Comment: cant you just append all the dataframes and create a label column?

Comment: I don't think so, as I don't want individual rows to be considered, I need all the data in each data frame to be considered for the classification.
I'm also not sure that would work for testing, as I need to test on entire data frames

Comment: you should give some example data since your explanation isnt really clear. in my understanding you have, lets say, 3 dataframes for which you have one label each. for all the dataframes you have the same column names (which correspond to features, i guess) and values for these

Comment: what do you mean with "You need all the data in the data frame to be able to determine the label."?

Comment: can you paste your sample dataframe , I don't think you can do that staright away , you need to express all your data as a single row and then label , some sort  of pivoting or transposing your data might help

Comment: Yeah so in the data frame the rows correspond to time and the columns correspond to features surrounding a product. We need to know how each of those features develop over time to be able to classify it.

Comment: Have added an example if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct idea: for a classification model to work, you need to have the data for a single sample in a single row of your resulting dataframe. What you have in your example is some sort of cross table, but what you need is flat table. Luckily with pandas, you can easily create the flat table by using `unstack()`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10, 1000], [2, 12, 1245], [3, 20, 1837], [4, 18, 1837]],
                      columns=['Time', 'Measure1', 'Measure2'])
>>> s = df.set_index('Time').unstack()
>>> s
          Time
Measure1  1         10
          2         12
          3         20
          4         18
Measure2  1       1000
          2       1245
          3       1837
          4       1837
dtype: int64
```

The result is a `pd.Series` (= single column) with a MultiIndex. You can then add the label to the measurements and concatenate all data into a single dataframe.

```py
>>> s['label'] = 'l1'
>>> df = pd.concat([s,s,s], axis=1).T
>>> df
     Measure1             Measure2                   label
Time        1   2   3   4        1     2     3     4      
0          10  12  20  18     1000  1245  1837  1837    l1
1          10  12  20  18     1000  1245  1837  1837    l1
2          10  12  20  18     1000  1245  1837  1837    l1
```

Using a MultiIndex in the columns is a bit unwieldy, but you could replace them by

```
>>> df.columns = ['_'.join(str(x) for x in c).strip('_') for c in df.columns]
>>> df
  Measure1_1 Measure1_2 Measure1_3  ... Measure2_3 Measure2_4 label
0         10         12         20  ...       1837       1837    l1
1         10         12         20  ...       1837       1837    l1
2         10         12         20  ...       1837       1837    l1
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed Rob, thanks for your response